# iPhone - Objective C - Play Video Fullscreen in Landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, avplayerviewcontroller

I've looked and found some similar questions asked before. But none of the offered solutions work for me so I'm asking this.

I'm writing an IOS App that starts with a Tab bar, each tab View Controller has an embedded Navigation Controller. I am able to stream video and play it using AVPlayerViewController but am not able to force it to start in Landscape mode (even if the phone is in portrait mode. If I flip the phone, it does become full screen as Landscape mode.

Here is the code section that I have that streams the Video:

```
-(void) startPlayback {

  NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString: pathToVideoStream];

  NSLog(@"Entered %s - Will now try to play video at NSURL: %@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, streamURL );

  AVPlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
  moviePlayer.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:streamURL];
  [self presentViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES completion:nil];
  moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
  [moviePlayer.player play];

}
```

I have added the suggestions from this post:
[Play Video In Landscape when entire application is Portait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759996/play-video-fullscreen-in-landscape-mode-when-my-entire-application-is-in-lock-i)

But that did not force the video to play in Landscape mode. I see other suggestions about using CGAffine, but my first instinct says that can't be the correct way to flip the Video. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this.

I created a subclass of AVPlayerViewController and called LandscapeAVPlayerViewController. In the implementation of the subclass I overrode two methods:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

   [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; // allows Left and Right both
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;   // prefers Right in portrait mode
}
```

And then back in the startPlayback Method I changed the code to :

```
-(void) startPlayback {

   NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString: pathToVideoStream];

   LandscapeAVPlayerViewController *landscapeMoviePlayerVC =  [[LandscapeAVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

   landscapeMoviePlayerVC.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:streamURL];

   [self presentViewController:landscapeMoviePlayerVC animated:YES completion:nil];
   [landscapeMoviePlayerVC.player play];

}
```

That's all I needed to do.